# Did web essentials remove Less editor?

Tags: web-essentials

I just updated web essentials and now I have no syntax highlighting or compile. In the change notes I can read that "Removed LESS/CoffeeScript editors" in version 2.5, but the options for less are still there?!.

Whatta? Why?

Comment: Not to be facetious, but if the release notes say 'Removed LESS/CoffeeScript editors', that's probably what happened. The options may just not have been updated yet. Don't see how a question ending Why? can be usefully answered on SO, therefore VTC.

Comment: I see now that they expect you to use Web Tools 2012, which has the Less support.

Comment: See http://madskristensen.net/post/Web-Tools-20122-and-Web-Essentials.aspx.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The LESS editor was moved to web tools 2012.2 as an official feature of visual studio 2012.

Here is a link with more info and the option to download.

http://madskristensen.net/post/Web-Tools-20122-and-Web-Essentials.aspx

Comment: This is not cool, it's a way to make people trust tools like this less.

Comment: @blaster care you explain your comment? It went from 3rd party to directly integrated into Visual Studio.